# Error: spawn EACCES on AWS Lambda using html-to-pdf package

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) and trying to convert html to pdf on AWS Lambda using node js, but I get the error `Error: spawn EACCES" message`:

```
START RequestId: 8bc188e7-8249-41d7-b8f7-8a2585ea8e46 Version: $LATEST
2019-06-07T20:44:44.824Z    8bc188e7-8249-41d7-b8f7-8a2585ea8e46    ************** start
2019-06-07T20:44:45.025Z    8bc188e7-8249-41d7-b8f7-8a2585ea8e46    Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
    at PDF.PdfExec [as exec] (/var/task/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:87:28)
    at PDF.PdfToBuffer [as toBuffer] (/var/task/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:44:8)
    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:17:35)
END RequestId: 8bc188e7-8249-41d7-b8f7-8a2585ea8e46
REPORT RequestId: 8bc188e7-8249-41d7-b8f7-8a2585ea8e46  Duration: 345.46 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 39 MB  
RequestId: 8bc188e7-8249-41d7-b8f7-8a2585ea8e46 Process exited before completing request
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple ideas:

1. How do you package and upload your code?
   lambda requires the files to have read access for all users, particularly "other", if this is missing you will receive a non-obvious error when trying to call the function. The fix is simple enough, perform a 'chmod a+r *' before creating your zip file. If the code is visible in the inline editor adding an empty line and saving will also fix the problem, presumably by overwriting the file with the correct permissions.
2. Where are you saving the converted file / are you using lambda tmp directory? Might be a wrong path
3. Lambda timeout doesn't allow enough time to execute your function. Less possible, but due to mentioning process exited before completion I would double check. Check timeout settings on your function

Comment: You can strike #3 in this case.  The process exits immediately due to the exception, after only 345 ms.  Also, might the lack of execute in addition to read be an issue on #1?

Comment: @di-v, for 1) you want me to run that command and zip it on Linux box I assume?  I can try that. 2) I am using buffer

Comment: @michael-sqlbot I gave it AWSLambdaFullAccess , AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSLambdaExecute

Comment: @wil `EACCESS` isn't that kind of "access."  It's a Linux system error code (code 13) that translates to the message `Permission denied` -- the same thing that occurs if you're trying to run a program on a machine that your user doesn't have permission to run.  `chmod a+r filename` *and* `chmod a+x filename` before building the zip are *probably* what's needed.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot  thanks, it was permission issue.  I had no idea aws lambda needed this.

Comment: I wonder if I can use bash to run chmod command on windows?  I ran it on Linux vm.

Comment: @will there is no direct alternative for this in windows. Powershell on windows 10 allows the command, but doesnt do shit. Terminal emulators couldnt do that properly either 
From my experience, packing lambda in a same way from windows machine as from linux wm would not be transparent. You either have to start using serverless or other plugins for packing from one specific type of OS or doesnt mix it. I had lots of issues with dependencies packed when mixing deployments from local windows machine & from own linux server. Stick to one OS, preferably linux because that what lambda is using

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you saved my week xD I was stucked with my lambda and chmod a+r and a+x on phnatonjs binary did the trick! Thank you so much!!!